# Tile game collision detection with sprite moving to arbitary (x,y)

Tags: language-agnostic, collision-detection

So I am struggling with some logic for collision detection in my game.

I have a grid of tiles(images), all representative of a value in a 2D array, so the location of tile N would be (column m, row n). Each tiles dimensions are set by (windowDimensions/numberOfTiles).

I have a moveable sprite, that is the same dimensions as the tile images, however, this sprite moves to (x,y) pixel locations (to move smoothly).

I am looking for suggestions to find the grid location of the moveable sprite using its (x,y) pixel coordinates in the window.

All suggestions welcome,
Regards,
Jack Hunt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide `x` and `y` by `tileWidth` and `tileHeight`, and then either take the floor or ceiling of the result (depending on what you want).

Comment: Thank you, so obvious yet works a charm. I was way over complicating this in my head. Thank you!